# android TableLayout:difference between shrinkColumns and stretchColumns

Tags: android, xml, tablelayout, tablerow

i'm working on android os so I have a small question and I think the answer is small too :)
what is the difference between shrinkColumns and stretchColumns in tableLayout?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow Did u search in Google ?? Read it first before asking questions in stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html